# How to get a reference to an object created on an iframe from the main frame

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe and I need to use that iframe to create a new object from a script running in the main frame. The problem is, when I instantiate an object in this way, it gives back undefined, so I do not have a way to get the reference and manipulate the object.

The example shows what is going on:

```
//main.html
<html>
    <script>
        var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];

        //it gives back undef instead of the new object
        var foo = new iframe.contentWindow.Foo();
    </script>

    <iframe src="second.html"></iframe>
</html>

//second.html
<html>
    <script>

        window.Foo = function() {
            this.bar = "BAR";
        }

    </script>
</html>
```

I know that this is caused, because the execution environment differs for the main frame and the iframe, but is there any way to get a reference for the object created on the iframe?

I tried to put the variable to the iframe's global scope, hoping that it works, but it is still undefined:

```
//main.html
<html>
    <script>
        var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];

        //I hoped this helps (because now the variable is on the same
        //global environment), but still undefined
        iframe.contentWindow.foo = new iframe.contentWindow.Foo();
    </script>

    <iframe src="second.html"></iframe>
</html>

//second.html
<html>
    <script>

        window.Foo = function() {
            this.bar = "BAR";
        }

    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: are they on the same origin?

Comment: Yeah, the iframe was created on the main frame. (so I can get to the iframe like this: document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0]; )

Comment: `Foo` seems to be called fine, but you're not returning anything from it. If `iframe.contentWindow` was `undefined`, calling `Foo` of it would throw a reference error, it wouldn't return `undefined`.

Comment: Yes it is. And the invokation works, the object gets created on the iframe (I can see it's side effect). The only problem that I don't get back the reference to it, it gives back undefined.

Comment: `()` doesn't refer, it calls ...

Comment: How about using `window.onload` and then trying to call the function in the iframe in the handler?

Comment: Unfortunately I can call Foo only from the main frame (this is part of a bigger application, that I can not change.)

Answer (score 0):

On the main page yoou define the name of your page:

```
<head>
    <script>  
    window.name = "home";
    var home = window;

    var NS_MAIN = {             
       init:function(){
          alert(home.SECOND.globalVal);
                }   

            };
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="frame" src="secondPage.html" border="1" width="50%" height="50%"></iframe>
```

your secondPage

```
 <head>
           <script>  

           var NS_SECOND = {    

                globalVal:null,

                init:function(){
                       home.SECOND= this;
                       NS_SECOND.globalVal="Hello";

                }   

            };
          </script>
      </head>
      <body>            


      </body>
```

Comment: That's not the problem. I can invoke the function of the iframe. My problem is that I can not get hold of the return value, because it is always undefined.

Comment: If you use a global value?

Comment: var NS_MAIN = {   

globalValue : null,
          
       init:function(){
          alert("Hello");
                }   

            };

the you save in the globalValue your return to the function

MAIN.NS_MAIN.globalValue = "yourValue";

then you can invoke that globalValue from every iframe

Comment: That's similar, what I tried to do in my second example, but it's not working. See this line: iframe.contentWindow.foo = new iframe.contentWindow.Foo();

Comment: I don't know if I  understand well.
You tried to override the function in your main page. But in my opinion,
you have to define your function in main page and then, override that function in your second page.

Comment: In my main page I only called a constructor function, which exists on the iframe. (I don't think I try override anything)

Comment: Not really. How am I supposed to call NS_MAIN.init() ? (when I copy your example nothing happens because the init is never called, maybe I don't understand something)

Comment: you are right, sorry. Try to call init form on the onload document or in a onclick event

Comment: I edited your code to put your suggestions into it. But if you run this in browser you can see that it is not correct. On the second page home is undefined so it throws an Error.

Comment: can you include in both documents the same js file?